# Nested Drag and Drop with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, nested

I'm creating vertical nested drag and drop with [react-beautiful-dnd](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?selectedKind=single%20vertical%20list&selectedStory=basic&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). I have referred some [answers in github](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/293)

I have forked from sandbox and created new one for vertical nested drag and drop.
When I change the inside DND, outside DND changes the values not inside DND.

[image]

**CODE**

```
 onDragEnd(result) {
    // dropped outside the list
    console.log("innner drag");
    if (!result.destination) {
      return;
    }

    const items = reorder(
      this.state.items,
      result.source.index,
      result.destination.index
    );

    this.setState({
      items
    });
  }
```

**DEMO** Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ozq53zmj6

Comment: In react-beautiful-dnd, all onDragEnd events are handled by the root DragDropContext. Currently, nested DragDropContexts [aren't supported](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/302). In your ServiceCommandUnit.js file, you don't actually use the `onDragEnd` function anywhere. My recommendation would be to lift the state of ServiceCommandUnit.js to index.js, and check the `droppableId` within the result to check which "list" should be handled everytime `onDragEnd` is called.

Comment: Also, a tip: the "draggableID" can be any string you want. So, if you want you can embed all the information to identify the draggable content as an object, then JSON.stringify it and use that as the "draggableID". That's what I currently do, despite it kinda not being intended that way. ^_^

Comment: For those like me coming from Google, note that `DragDropContext`s that are completely unrelated to each other are totally fine. So you could have a DragDropContext inside a DragDropContext and if you're not dragging between them that's totally fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`react-beautiful-dnd` doesn't support nested drag-drop as of now and it's low priority item as per their roadmap. You need to handle everything on outer `<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}>`. It doesn't give parent information by default in `result` object, so I have kept that information in child `Droppable` component. See the below demo if this works for you.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4ow4r45v

**Edit:** Refer below sandbox for a more generic code snippet where you will be able to apply nested drag-drop across parent container.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v2yvpjn7n

Comment: In the second example is there a way to make the items dragable between levels? Like I would like to move `subitem1` under root or `items2` under subitems of `items1`. Or is there any other library that can achieve this DaD behaviour?

Comment: In the second example, you can reorder individual `items`, you can reorder `subItems` inside an `item`, you can drag-drop `subItems` from one `item` to another `item`. If I understood your question correctly, you want to move a `subItem` from `item2` container to `item1` container and that's possible. You can try it out in the `codesandbox`

Comment: What I was looking for was [this functionality](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/core/tree/example/drag_and_drop_with_nesting). While this package isn't ideal because I'll have to transform my data to required format by the package it does what I need.

Comment: Yes `react-beautiful-dnd` doesn't support nested drag-drop as of now, that's why moving all the logic to parent is the only option left with this library. You can try [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about)

Comment: Based on that second example, would it be possible to allow `item` to be dropped between `subitems`, and a `subitem` to be dropped between `items`?

Comment: I was looking for the solution in the first example, `react-beautiful-dnd` should add this in their examples as well.

Comment: This is an absolutely lovely bit of code, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

just give type to your outer and inner droppable, on drag end you have to check the type of your droppable,and reorder accordingly.

```
onDragEnd = ({ type, destination, source }) => {

    if (source && destination && type) {
        let parentId = source.droppableId;
        let srcIndex = source.index;
        let destIndex = destination.index;

        if (type == "Inner") {
            //method for reordering the order of the inner items
            reorderInner(parentId, srcIndex, destIndex)
        }
        else if (type == "Outer") {
            //method for reordering the order of parent items
            reorderOuter(srcIndex,destIndex)
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: thanks. it's working however, inner dnd is returning back to it's place because destination object is empty when we are dropping it. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

[@debajit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5084280/debajit-majumder)'s answer works like a charm. I've updated his code to latest react version (18.2.0) with FC and latest react-beautiful-dnd (13.1.0) versions => https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dnd-across-parent-forked-p7ijli?

Answer (score 0):

I have also been through the same problem and I also used the react-beautiful-dnd but with many custom changes it works but not smoothly and then I have came to see another package named react-nestable and it works as i needed. I am putting a link for that package below - [react-nestable npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nestable)